# Need Help with Integration Testing a ROS2 Project (Galactic, Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: ros2, integration

I am a beginner with ROS2, and I would like to develop a comprehensive test suite for my project. I have already created unit tests for my ROS2 packages, and the next step that I wish to take is to start creating integration tests. However I cannot seem to get started with the task, and I was hoping you might be able to push me in the right direction.

Without going into the specifics of the project at hand, lets imagine I want to create an integration test to test the Publisher/Subscriber communications between two nodes. These nodes are defined in two different packages, one being a C++ package and the other a Python package. So, to get going with this task, lets create the two packages:

```
cd ~
mkdir -p ros2_ws/src
cd ros2_ws/src

ros2 pkg create --build-type ament_cmake --node-name cpp_pub_node cpp_pkg
ros2 pkg create --build-type ament_python --node-name py_sub_node py_pkg
```

In the cpp_pkg/src/cpp_pub_node.cpp source file I define a simple Publisher class:

```
#include <cstdio>

#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/string.hpp"

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class Publisher : public rclcpp::Node
{
  public:
    Publisher()
    : Node("publisher"), count_(0)
    {
      publisher_ = this->create_publisher<std_msgs::msg::String>("/test_topic", 10);
      timer_ = this->create_wall_timer(500ms, std::bind(&Publisher::timer_callback, this));
    }

  private:
    void timer_callback()
    {
      auto message = std_msgs::msg::String();
       = "Hello, world!"; // + std::to_string(count_++);
      RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Publishing: '%s'", message.data.c_str());
      publisher_->publish(message);
    }
    rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr timer_;
    rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::String>::SharedPtr publisher_;
    size_t count_;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);

  rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<Publisher>());

  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

I have made the required changes to package.xml and CMakeLists.txt regarding rclcpp and std_msgs.

As a counterpart to this publisher, I have defined a Subscriber class in the py_pkg/py_pkg/py_sub_node.py source file:

```
import rclpy

from rclpy.node import Node
from std_msgs.msg import String

class Subscriber(Node):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__('subscriber')
        self._subscription = self.create_subscription(
            String,
            '/test_topic',
            self.listener_callback,
            10)
        self._subscription  # prevent unused variable warning
        
        self.get_logger().info("Subscriber Created!")

    def listener_callback(self, msg):
        self.get_logger().info('I heard: "%s"' % msg.data)


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    minimal_subscriber = Subscriber()
    
    rclpy.spin(minimal_subscriber)

    minimal_subscriber.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have made the required changes to package.xml.

Great, we have two nodes in two different packages that can communicate with one another. Now, how would I go on with creating an integration test that would verify the fact that this communication does indeed occur succesfully?

I have tried to play with the `launch_test` tool, but I don't seem to undestand how to use it properly. However, if I understood correctly, using the `launch_test` tool will allow me to examine stdout and the exit codes of the processes. How would this allow me to test the communication between the two nodes, if instead of logging the messages the callbacks would simply perform some operations without logging anything?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.